# How to track resource (eg. image) load time in WebWiew(Client)

Tags: android

I load a webpage in a `WebView` with a `WebViewClient`. The webpage has a couple of images, some css, javascript etc. and I want to find out, how long it took for the resource files (jpegs, .js, .css files etc) to load.

To get the total page load time, I override the `WebViewClient`s `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished`, add some timers, and subtract. Is it possible (and how) to also get load times for each resource on the page?

So basically, i would like a result that tells me (eg.) the page took 5.3 seconds to load, image1.jpg took 2.4s image2.jpg took 3.7s, script.js took 0.9 seconds, etc.

Edit: I need to do that on the phone itself. I'm not trying to optimize a webpage, but to write an app that does that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Chrome Devtools Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews) which allows you to connect your Android WebView to the Chrome browser on your PC/Mac/Linux machine.

Once connected. Chrome developer panel tab labelled `Network` to see how long each component took to load.

Detailed Instructions here: [Network Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/)

**NOTE** Chrome will has its own `adb` server so it may conflict with Android Studio. If Android Studio is having problems connecting via `adb`, make sure that Chrome DevTools Remote Debugging is off or even close/exit out of Chrome.

Comment: I would like to do that on the phone itself, so this doesn't help me unfortunately. I'm not trying to optimize a webpage, I'm trying to have an app to show this data.